# wikipedia dump phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, dump, wikipedia

Im trying to import the database file of wikipedia (titles only, 163M) from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/ with phpMyAdmin (I have a wamp configuration). I already changed the values on php.ini and Im receiving this error

```
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem
ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 1511
```

Where could be the problem? Do I need to change the coalltion from UTF8 to something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@user593712:

> Do I need to change the coalltion from UTF8

No, you need to ensure that the database you're importing to is UTF-8. See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki#Character_set

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that, there is an error around line number 1511.  Could you please check the contents around that line.  Sometimes, single quote "'" should be replaced by "\'" to import into the database.